# How to scroll PDF which is inside iframe in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

Here is the tag of document place under

```
<iframe height="900" width="100%" src="/attachments/download/Attachment.pdf" title="document"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

An inline frame is a construct which embeds a document into an HTML document so that **embedded data is displayed inside a subwindow** of the browser's window. This does not mean full inclusion and the two documents are independent, and both them are treated as complete documents, instead of treating one as part of the other.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe).

Now as per best practices to switch to an *iframe* you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* and you can use either of the following solutions:

  - Using `cssSelector`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src='/attachments/download/Attachment.pdf'][title='document']")));
    ```
  - Using `xpath`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='/attachments/download/Attachment.pdf' and @title='document']")));
    ```

Once you switch to the proper `<iframe>` you can **scroll** as well as **interact** with any element within the `<iframe>`

Comment: Thanks, but query is i have to scroll down PDF document which does not have any element to interact with PDF, the PDF placed under <document> <xhtml>:div tag please advise how to scroll the PDF